Question on proof of Localisation Theorem in Tom Dieck's Transformation Groups (Thm III.3.8)
I have a question regarding the Localisation Theorem (III.3.8) in Tom Dieck's Transformation groups, which states the following:
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, $(X,A)$ be a finite-dimensional relative $G$-complex. Suppose $X-A$ has finite orbit type with orbits isomorphic to $G/H$, where $S\cap\ker(H^\ast_G(G/G)\to H^\ast_G(G/H))\neq\emptyset$. Then the inclusion induces an isomorphism $$S^{-1}H^\ast_G(X)\cong S^{-1}H^\ast_G(A)$$.
In the proof, they consider $X$ as obtained via attaching map $$\phi:\coprod_jG/H_j\times(D^n,S^{n-1})\to(X,A)$$ and then state that there exists an isomorphism $$S^{-1}H^\ast_G(X,A)\cong S^{-1}H^\ast_G(\coprod_JG/H_j\times(D^n,S^{n-1}))$$ to make some argument considering the localised long exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)$.
My question: Why does the last isomorphism of the localised cohomology groups exist?
Note that the cohomology groups are considered as modules over $H^\ast(BG)$ and $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset lying in the center of $H^\ast(BG)$.

The isomorphism should already be true before localization. The proof should be more or less the same as in the non equivariant case.
